# How to loop react Native useState Array?

Tags: react-native

I am new comer to react-native.
I used useState array.
I need to set useState array data to Picker.(@react-native-community/picker)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. But on npmjs maybe you have noticed the package is no longer supported. I suggest you look for alternative packages.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState('USD');
const [currencies] = useState(['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR']);    

<Picker
      selectedValue={selected}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelected(itemValue)}
>
    {currencies.map((currency) => <Picker.Item key={currency} label={currency} value={currency} />)}  
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really detailed so I'm not sure I'm giving the best answer.

The fact the array was created using useState or not doesn't change the way you would assign it to the Picker.

Wouldn't this work?

```
<Picker>
{currencies.map((currency) => 
  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency} />
)}
</Picker>
```